# Windows Media Center spontaneously changing the language of program descriptions

Tags: language, windows-media-center

I have found a rather bizarre issue in Windows Media Center (WMC). I use WMC to record and watch movies (using my TV tuner card), and currently I have a few hundred movies stored on one of my hard drives. This has worked perfectly for several years now (both in Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows Vista, and Windows 7).

However, the last year or so, I have found that Media Center spontaneously *changes* the language of program descriptions. Normally, all program descriptions should be in Swedish, but many are now in Norwegian (and maybe Danish), as well as in German and some languages that I cannot even identify, like the following:

[image]

Strangely, this happens not only to new recordings, but to old ones as well. That is, a film I recorded several years ago, and that has always had its appropriate Swedish description, might get a new foreign-language description apparently at any time.

Is this a known issue? Is it a bug? (Although I am pretty sure my computer isn't infected with any kind of malware, it seems like a pretty strange bug indeed.) Is there a fix?

I should add that I have recently (more than a year ago) moved (within Sweden) and so I changed my ZIP code (WMC asks for this). Also, at my new location, I am only given an *analog* cable signal; previously, I had a digital (DVB-T) signal. (This sucks in its own right, but that's a separate issue.)